# Http protocol POST reading

Tags: java, http, post

I'm trying to read data from POST in java.
I have form in registrationForm.html:

```
<form action="registratrationResult.html" method="post">
  Mail:<br>
  <input type="text" name="mail">
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want to read this in java without using servlets. I read everything from browser and I got it:

```
>POST /registratrationResult.html HTTP/1.1
>Host: localhost:8080
>Connection: keep-alive
>Content-Length: 29
>Cache-Control: max-age=0
>Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>Origin: http://localhost:8080
>Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
>User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36
>Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>Referer: http://localhost:8080/registrationForm.html
>Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

I read that there should be something like:

```
parameter=value&also=another
```

How to get it?
Content-Length is changing, when I change input data.

Comment: I would like to see a code sample for how you get the POST response, and is it on the server or client side?

Answer (score 0):

The actual POST data is stored as key-value pairs, as you say, but they are put in the request body and not the header.

Sample using cURL:

```
$ curl --data "fname=stackoverflow&lname=user" --trace - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/demo_form_method_post.asp
```

Note the **send data** area in the output:

```
=> Send data, 30 bytes (0x1e)
0000: 66 6e 61 6d 65 3d 73 74 61 63 6b 6f 76 65 72 66 fname=stackoverf
0010: 6c 6f 77 26 6c 6e 61 6d 65 3d 75 73 65 72       low&lname=user
== Info: upload completely sent off: 30 out of 30 bytes
```

Post requests will usually be sent with a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, as mentioned in the send header.

Comment: Is it possible to read it in java?
How can I read request body?